# Android search button adds character to edittextbox 

Tags: android

I've and edittext where it's possible to enter characters to be used in a search string. When I enter a few characters and then press the search button however I get a trailing extra character on my search string "input" in the code bellow.

The character looks like a question mark with a square around it. When copied this is the result: 

I'd like to know why this is happening and how to remedy it?

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    Button searchbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_productinfo_search_button);

                    EditText searchInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_productinfo_search_input);
                    String input = searchInput.getText().toString().trim();
```

The EditText

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/activity_productinfo_search_input"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" 
                />
```

**Solved**
Removed from edittext: android:text="@string/fa_search" where fa_search= , font awesome string for a [search symbol](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/search/).

Comment: Try to set `android:inputType = text`to u r `EditText`

Comment: It would seem like this was the root to evil: android:text="@string/fa_search"

Comment: also post your fa_search string value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed from edittext: android:text="@string/fa_search", font awesome string for a search symbol.